# What book contains the context, discription and usage of Borel fields and $\sigma$-field?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I am studying probability and statistics and my book keeps referencing Borel fields and $\sigma$-fields, but I have not encountered them in my learning. What book what I read that would contain this information?

Comment: I actually think the [wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) is quite good

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you